# Where are variables stored that aren't in the stack?

Tags: stack

So for example if I had a program which used:

```
example = a.top
```

Where is the variable `example` stored?
and where are the values that are popped from the stack stored?

Extra:

If I had a basic program without functions that just added some values together like (variables would be equal to the user input):

```
a=8
b=2
c=5
d=2
answer = a+b+c+d
```

Would the variables a,b,c,d,answer be stored in the stack or another area?

Comment: They are stored in the current layer of the stack.  What are you really asking?

Comment: I thought the stack was limited in space? Surely not every variable in a program is in the stack? And where does the variable go once popped?

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer because it depends very much on the language you use.

Actually in C/C++/Pascal or traditional imperative languages, one will tell you they are on the stack or on the heap.

It can get complicated when you consider that some optimisations of the CPU will maybe make them stored in registers (even if you asked for a local variable) or even... nowhere: the compiler just remove the variable if is was useless.

One more possibility is when you have memory mapped data (mmap() called) you have data that may be in kernel space (some kernel page directly) or from a file (stored on the disk)

When using interpreted languages (python/perl/bash), they are handled by the interpreter itself, probably on the heap.

With functional languages, things get harder because such concepts (heap stack) have a really different meaning, one could say everything is on the stack (which has little to do with the C stack you may imagine)